# Filter workbook and copy range into another workbook at next available cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to filter workbook by looking for all blank entries in column E. Then copy range into another workbook at the next available row. When I run my code I get an error 'run time error' 1004 - PasteSpecial method of range class failed?? How would I debug this to be able to copy my range and paste into other workbook?

I have only just started learning VBA and learned most of what I know from google and watching youtube videos. I have tried to change the value for blank "", I have tried to add application.cutcopymode false

```
Sub MoveUnworkedtoDB()

`Dim wbk As Workbook
 Dim sh As Worksheet 
 Dim Lastrow As Long


' Open worksheet 1 and move unworked back to database

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
      "Workbook1")

  Set sh = wbk.Sheets("sheet1")

    'Clear any existing filters
  On Error Resume Next
    sh.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

  'Apply Filter
  sh.Range("A1:E9").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=""

  'copy Range
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    sh.Range("B2:e1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   'Clear Filter
  On Error Resume Next
    sh.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

  Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
    "workbook2")

 Set sh = wbk.Sheets("sheet1")

    Lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row

    Sheets("sheet1").Activate
    Cells(Lastrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, 
Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub`
```

runtime error 1004 - pastespecial method of range class failed

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on Excel version. You can't do this in Excel 2003 and older. You transpose 1000 rows to 1000 columns, old Excels have 256 columns only.
2. I corrected a bit Your code, now will work in newest versions, from 2007 up.

   ```
   Sub MoveUnworkedtoDB()

   Dim wbk As Workbook
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim Lastrow As Long
   Dim wbk2 As Workbook
   Dim sh2 As Worksheet


   ' Open worksheet 1 and move unworked back to database

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\temp\A.xlsx")

   Set sh = wbk.Sheets(1)

   'Clear any existing filters
   On Error Resume Next
   sh.ShowAllData
   On Error GoTo 0

   'Apply Filter
   sh.Range("A1:E9").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=""

   'copy Range
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   'sh.Range("B2:e1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   'Clear Filter
   On Error Resume Next
   sh.ShowAllData
   On Error GoTo 0

   Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\temp\B.xlsx")
   Set sh2 = wbk2.Sheets(1)

   With sh2
       Lastrow = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
       sh.Range("B2:e1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
       .Cells(Lastrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
   End With

   Application.CutCopyMode = False

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: With your code I am able to copy and paste to last row so thanks. The only problem is the information is copying across instead of copying down from columns A,B,C and D. Is there a way I can fix this please

Comment: Set Transpose:=False if You won't to pivot data.